# Uniform convergence and translation

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Define $f_n:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$$f_n(x) :=  f(x+n).$$

If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $g$, then f and g is uniformly continuous.

My first atttempt is as follows. By triangle ineqality, it holds

$$ |g(x) - g(y)| \leq |g(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - g(y)|.$$

The first and third can be made as small as possible. But, how about the second term?

Comment: Never mind, you're right. I was visualizing a change like $x^n$ on $[0,1]$ but that's not possible in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x+1)=\lim f(x+n+1)=\lim f(x+n)=g(x)$ so $g$ is continuous (by uniform convergence) and periodic. Hence $g$ is unifromly continuous.

Hint for uniform continuity of $f$: $|f(x+n)-f(x+m)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$ if $n,m$ are suffciently large. This shows that  for some $T>0$ we have $|f(x)-f(x+k)| < \epsilon$ for $x>T$ for all $k$. Can you finish?

Comment: What about whether $f$ is uniformly continuous? $f$ itself doesn't have to be periodic. And it doesn't seem like it has to be "eventually periodic" either, e.g. take $\sin(2\pi x)+e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Ian I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you for your help!! I understand!!